# Change Button Text inside foreach Loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a button , when i click on that button it should change it's text.it's there inside a foreach loop. But the problem is when i click on that button first buttons text change. I want to change the specific button text which i clicked ..How do i do that?

**Front-End Part**

```
@foreach($products as $product) 
    <button onclick="this.disabled=true;    quoteAdd('{!!$product->id!!}')" id="inquireButton"  class="btn btn-danger ">Inquire</button>
@endforeach
```

**Javascript Part**

```
function quoteAdd(productId)
{
    $("#inquireButton").html('Save');
    //    other code ..
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass button reference using `this` keyword to `quoteAdd` method like following.

**PHP**

```
@foreach($products as $product) 
    <button onclick="this.disabled=true; quoteAdd('{!!$product->id!!}', this)" id="inquireButton"  class="btn btn-danger ">Inquire</button>
@endforeach
```

**JS**

```
function quoteAdd(productId, button) {
    $(button).text('Save');
    //other code ..
}
```

**FYI** `id` should be unique for each element.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `id` attribute in HTML should be unique, so basically what you are doing is wrong (you shouldn't have fixed id within a loop).

Regardless this issue, you can do the following:

// Front-End Part

```
 @foreach($products as $product) 
    <button onclick="this.disabled=true; quoteAdd(this)" id="inquireButton_{!!$product->id!!}"  class="btn btn-danger ">Inquire</button>
 @endforeach
```

// Javascript Part

```
function quoteAdd(el)
{
    $(el).html('Save');
    // other code ..
}
```